# Javascript's ajax won't run on browser's back button

Tags: javascript, ajax

My javascript ajax script seems to not work whenever a page was loaded through the back button or forward button of the browser

```
//
function IncreasePopularity(){
  var hiddenid = <?php echo $id; ?>; //$id is the id of the user being rated
  $.ajax ({
    url: 'IncreasePopularity.php',
    data: 'id='+hiddenid,
      success: function(data){
     alert('haha');
    }
  });
}
```

i am triggering the event by

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    IncreasePopularity();
});
```

the script works on refresh or when the page has been loaded normally (by click the button to enter the page) and it also updates the database but when the page was loaded through the back or forward of the browser it only alerts 'haha' but it doesn't increase the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569759/basic-ajax-cache-issue

Comment: thank you its working now :) updated the question with the correct code

Comment: Surely the only way a user would hit “back” and have your code trigger is if they already “liked” that particular user.  So this is a second, or duplicate “like”?

Comment: actually no, this is a chat room just changed some codes due to some contracts that i signed, the number of user will decrease when a user leaves the room, i have an unload script, so basically when a user presses back it doesn't load the increaseuser script which might cause the room to keep decreasing if the user keeps doing the bug 

EDIT: misunderstanding of the comment

Comment: Please, write answers into answers, not into the question.

Comment: ok sorry about that the fix is to just add the cache:false on the ajax script

Comment: No. Create an answer for your own question and marki as solved. Without this, people will probably continue to consider it as non solved. So if solution is founded, community need to know it.

Comment: ok sorry, it says i need to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to just add the cache:false, into the ajax script

```
//
function IncreasePopularity(){
  var hiddenid = <?php echo $id; ?>; //$id is the id of the user being rated
  $.ajax ({
    url: 'IncreasePopularity.php',
    data: 'id='+hiddenid,
    cache: false,
      success: function(data){
     alert('haha');
    }
  });
}
```